# Python MySQL insert behavior

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, sql-insert

I believe I am having trouble with how MySQLdb handles null string inserts. For example, in my insert statement the last parameter in the values list may be the empty string. Here is what my values list looks like before I try to execute the query:

```
before:  ('FOUND', 'noise', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'noise NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA', 'FOUND', '')

Error: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I also tried replacing the empty string with `None` and `[None]` with no luck...

Here is my code:

```
qry = "insert into golden_table (topic, week1, week2, week3, week4, week5, week6, week7, week10, week11, week12, clust_list, nGram, hash_tag) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
        try:
            for k in gt:
                a = ((k[0],) + tuple(gt[(k[0], k[1], k[2])]))
                b = tuple([str(reduce(lambda x,y: x+' '+y, gt[(k[0], k[1], k[2])]))])
                if k[2] == '':
                    c = (k[1], '')
                else:
                    c = (k[1], k[2])
                print "before: ", (a+b+c)
                qry = qry % (a+b+c)
                print "after: ", qry
                cur.execute(qry)
                con.commit()
```

1. What is causing the conversion failure?
2. How can I fix this?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The error is unrelated to MySQL (as you probably realized after titling your question).  You simply have a number of elements in `(a + b + c)` that is different from the number of `%s` placeholders in the original `qry`.  What do you get if you add `d = a + b + c` before the first `print` and then use `d` instead of `(a+b+c)` in the following two lines?

Comment: I should note that if I copy and paste the printed query string into mysql, it will perform the insertion without a problem... The problem is with MySQLdb...

Comment: Yes, of course copy and paste will work.  The problem is the Python syntax you're using in `qry = qry % (a+b+c)`.  `cur.execute` almost certainly does not have a `str formatting` vulnerability inside it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is wrong with it? When I print `qry` after executing `qry = qry % (a+b+c)`, I have a valid SQL statement that I could copy and paste into a MySQL buffer -- If I knew more programming tricks I should "hack" through this by piping all the queries the MySQL buffer! hahahah

Comment: If that line is working, then why is the `print "after: ", qry` line not being printed?